# Replacing parts of a string with characters JAVA

Tags: java, string, methods

I know I was here earlier asking something similar, but I think I have narrowed down what i want to ask.
Ok, so I am making a program that plays the game of hangman on the jedit console. The user will guess one character at a time. At the beginning of the game, the program will display asterisks the same length of the word they are guessing. They have as many guesses as letters in the word. When they get a letter correct, the program will display the letters in place of asterisks. Here is an example of what the console should look like.

if the word is homework   ************

they guess the letter e   *****e******   (the bold e just happened because stars so that, it doesn't need to be bold)

then they guess the letter h   h**e****

etc until there are no more asterisks

So I created a method that prints out the number of asterisks based on the number of letters in the word. I don't know how to place the letters in the place of the asterisks. I want to know if I should make a method that replaces the asterisks, or how else I can go about this. Thank you in advance for the help.

p.s I am not asking for anyone to dump code on me, that is not what I want. Just having help, and me having someone to ask questions to about things that I don't understand would be nice. by the way, I am in an intro to computer science class, so my knowledge of java is fairly low.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could approach this.  The first that popped into my head is that you could start with a char[] the same length as the answer string.  Look up the Arrays class for an easy way to fill it with asterisks.  As the user guesses letters, search the answer string for that letter and replace the corresponding indexes of the char[].  Then construct a String from the char[] and display it.

Comment: I just want to be sure I am understanding you.
So, I should instead of having a method that has the asterisks, have an array instead.  Then look in the string that is the word and replace the asterisk with the letter at the same index?
Thank you again for the help.

Comment: Well... are you? :)

Edit: It only showed me the first sentence of your comment until I posted mine.  It sounds like you understand what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make something more clever, make a list of all the `chars` guessed so far and each time you want to print the word just go over each letter and replace it with * if not in the set.

Short: make a set of all the guesses so far. You don't have to work on the same data structure as you show the user.

Comment: But I would have to start off at just printing asterisks and then revealing each letter. Would I be able to do what you are saying, but backwards?

Comment: its not backwards.. it's exactly like I said, each letter that is not in set turns *

Answer (score 0):

I would use a list of characters instead of String for ********.

```
List<Character> hiddenWord = new ArrayList<Character>();
```

Instantiate the list with the number of * you need.

Create a function that will receive the guessed letter.
Check if the word contains that letter (use indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex) repeatedly until you get -1  - read about it [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int,%20int%29)), and for each result you get that is !=-1, set the position in the array to be that letter (something like `hiddenWord.set(poz, letter)`, where poz is the result of indexOf and letter is the guessed letter).

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuffer insead String. In class StringBuffer exists method [setCharAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#setCharAt%28int,%20char%29).
Breifly, you will have variable `String word` - for guessing word, and `StringBuilder guess` for asterisks and guesed letters. When letter is guessed you will update `guess` with setCharAt.